# Is the efficiency of std::map::find related to the data size of the value?

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, stl

I used a `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, class B>` to save the information of a grid map, the class B consists of about 10000 Bytes data. I found that it takes about 10ms for 40000 times `find` operation, although the map only has four key-value. When I decreased the data size of class B to 2500 Bytes, the cost is also decreased to about 3.5ms. I knew the time complexity of the find operation is O(log(N)), what's the reason of this phenomenon?

Comment: You have a find and that uses a comparison - would an unordered map be quicker?

Comment: You'd have to prepare and show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get a good answer. Otherwise we'll just be speculating.

Comment: @Useless MCVE in all honours, but this gives quite some context on the matter. It's a rather general question and I doubt it's improved by showing three lines of code that...do exactly what he describes.

Comment: I used the gettimeofday function to compute the time cost of the 40000 times find operation and found it is different when the data size of the class B is different

Comment: Big O notation != runtime performance. But in this case the problem might be with data locality. If value is big there might be considerable distances between keys to perform comparison. You may try to replace value item with a pointer to value or to in index of value stored somewhere else and check the results.

Comment: it is difficult to paste all of my code in there, although I understand it is more helpful.

Comment: "difficult to paste all of my code in there" shouldn't such test take like 10 lines?

Comment: Show the code and the build script.

Comment: @SteveXu try with `class B { char embiggen[10000]; }` rather than whatever B is in your current code. (The M of MCVE)

Comment: I tried something like what you described on my computer and I cannot reproduce the phenomenon, find takes the same time regardless of the size of the value.

Comment: @ChristianRau - it gives _some_ context, but I have no confidence it really includes everything important. It doesn't seem plausible that the extra cache misses take ~6.5ms for a container with four elements, which means the problem lies in the details _not_ shown. Eg, something is getting copied, profiling includes creating & populating the container, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious and tried a simple test. The test code is below (compiled with VS2015).

This is what I got when I ran the code in release build (optimizations on):

> ```
> Value10k: 0.126498 ms
> Value2k: 0.121991 ms
> ```

This is the output in debug builds:

> ```
> Value10k: 120.187 ms
> Value2k: 95.5364 ms
> ```

In release builds the difference is negligible; in debug builds there seems to be some difference (although, for performance data, I tend to prefer release builds).

I don't know the implementation details of the `map::find` method. Anyway, note that the big-O notation is only one part of the story. Another important aspect to consider for performance is cache-friendliness of your data, data locality, etc.

I don't even know if your class B has some expensive copy operations going on.

Anyway, I'd suggest *measuring* your code performance, and compare with other variations like using a `unique_ptr<B>` or `shared_ptr<B>` for your map's value.

---

Compilable test code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

template <int DimT>
struct Value
{
    char Data[DimT];
};

typedef Value<10000> Value10k;
typedef Value<2000> Value2k;


long long Counter() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

long long Frequency() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

void PrintTime(const long long start, const long long finish, const char * const msg)
{
    cout << msg << ": " << (finish - start) * 1000.0 / Frequency() << " ms\n";
}

bool IsEven(int n)
{
    return (n % 2) == 0;
}

int main() 
{
    map<pair<int, int>, Value10k> m1;
    m1[make_pair(0, 0)] = Value10k{};
    m1[make_pair(0, 1)] = Value10k{};
    m1[make_pair(1, 0)] = Value10k{};
    m1[make_pair(1, 1)] = Value10k{};

    constexpr int searchCount = 40000;

    auto start = Counter();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchCount; i++)
    {
        int x{};
        int y{};
        if (IsEven(i))
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            x = 1;
            y = 0;
        }
        auto search = m1.find(make_pair(x, y));
    }
    auto finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "Value10k");


    map<pair<int, int>, Value2k> m2;
    m2[make_pair(0, 0)] = Value2k{};
    m2[make_pair(0, 1)] = Value2k{};
    m2[make_pair(1, 0)] = Value2k{};
    m2[make_pair(1, 1)] = Value2k{};

    start = Counter();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchCount; i++)
    {
        int x{};
        int y{};
        if (IsEven(i))
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            x = 1;
            y = 0;
        }
        auto search = m2.find(make_pair(x, y));
    }
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "Value2k");
}
```